# How can I deserialize json array?

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I have json and an array inside it what looks like:

```
{ 
  "data" : [
    [int],
    [...],
    [..n]
  ]
}
```

Can I get array from "data" using JsonUtility? Or any other way?

For now, I can get "data" using following code:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class ObjectProperties
{
    public int[] data;
    public string color;
}
public void LoadFromJson()
{
    objectProperties = JsonUtility.FromJson<ObjectProperties>(File.ReadAllText(Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/CubeSettings.json"));
}
```

And I can get any data but array I need.

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Can you please write it in a language that you know well and use e.g. google translate?

Comment: So use objectProperties.data. What's the problem?

Comment: So is there any issue? Otherwise I would say "Just like this" ... **EXCEPT** is your structure really `[[1], [2], [3], ... ]` .. in this case your JSON is either wrong and should rather be `[1,2,3,...]` or you have nested arrays (`int[][]`) which isn't supported by the built-in `JsonUtility` ...

Comment: @Sheradil, I updated my question. Please check, and ask me if you still don't understand something.

Comment: please clearify what you **expect** the code to do and what you **actually** get. From the code above I can't see any problem and you should be able to get the array via `objectProperties.data`.

Comment: @MrMoeinM, yeah, I tried to use objectProperties.data[] but I can't get any array element 
 and all of elements in my array are empty. I can get only lenght of array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the structure actually is e.g.

```
{ 
  "data" : [
    [1],
    [2],
    [3]
  ]
}
```

This is a **nested array** `int[][]` (an array where each element is an array itself).

So either the JSON should rather look like

```
{ 
  "data" : [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ]
}
```

or - if changing the JSON is not an option for you - your c# structure rather has to be

```
[System.Serializable]
public class ObjectProperties
{
    public int[][] data;
    public string color;
}
```

**BUT** such nested arrays are not supported by the built-in `JsonUtility` (see [Script Serialization](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html)).

For this you would need to use a different library like e.g. `Newtonsoft .NET JSON` (available as a [Package via the Package Manager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.nuget.newtonsoft-json@2.0/manual/index.html))

```
var json = File.ReadAllText(Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/CubeSettings.json"));
var objectProperties = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObjectProperties>(json);
```

This also means the field will not be visible/editable in the Inspector and will not be saved together with the scene or prefabs in Unity.

Comment: thanks a lot, that's what I exactly needed :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume 'data' is array itself, but not array of array.
So it should be

```
{"data":[1,2,3],"color":"red"}
```

Also you should define get/set to include fields into serialization:

```
[System.Serializable]
public class ObjectProperties 
{
    public int[] data { get; set; }
    public string color { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can run it:

```
var objectProperties = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ObjectProperties>(...);
```

Comment: You should remove the `{get; set}` and stick to fields in order to maintain the serialization in the Unity Editor - in other words to be able to save the values in the scene and prefabs and to be able to edit the values via the Inspector

Comment: It's needed for JsonSerializer that  I use in my example.